# Distinct values with MAX and MIN from Access Database in VB NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to help HR by arranging the time attendance data from biometric readers in a more readable way. The output from the readers are summarized in a Access database. The output looks like the image bellow:

[image]

Each employee can have 1 IN and 1 EXIT daily (`f_ReaderName` column ). Some of them swipe the card multiple times and multiple INs or EXITs are recorded. How can I query the database or arrange this programmatically to have, per each `Data` column value, a single record for each `f_CardNO` and 2 columns: a MAX of `Ora`  where `f_ReaderName` = 1-1[In] and a MIN of `Ora` where `f_ReaderName` = 1-1[Exit]?

Is it any way I can achieve this? A hint will be more than useful. Thanks a bunch!

LE: Manage to get to this query, but cannot be parsed, what am I doing wrong in the syntax:

```
SELECT
  CR.f_CardNO,
  Format(CR.f_ReadDate, 'Short Date') AS Data,
  CR.f_ConsumerName,
  CR.f_GroupName,
  CR.f_ReaderName,
  (
    SELECT
      ISNULL(MAX(FORMAT(CR.f_ReadDate, 'Long Time')), 0) AS Expr1 
    FROM
      v_d_CardRecord CR1 
    WHERE
      (
        CR.f_ReadDate = CR1.f_ReadDate 
        AND CR.CardNO = CR1.CardNO 
        AND CR1.F_ReaderName = # 1 - 1[In] # 
      )
  )
  As OraIntrare,
  (
    SELECT
      ISNULL(MIN(FORMAT(CR.f_ReadDate, 'Long Time')), 0) AS Expr1 
    FROM
      v_d_CardRecord CR1 
    WHERE
      (
        CR.f_ReadDate = CR1.f_ReadDate 
        AND CR.CardNO = CR1.CardNO 
        AND CR1.F_ReaderName = # 1 - 1[Exit] # 
      )
  )
  As OraIesire 
FROM
  v_d_CardRecord CR 
WHERE
  (
    CR.f_ReadDate > # 12 / 1 / 2016 # 
  )
ORDER BY
  CR.f_ConsumerName,
  Format(CR.f_ReadDate, 'Short Date') 
GROUP BY
  CR.f_CardNO,
  Data,
  CR.f_ConsumerName,
  CR.f_GroupName,
  CR.f_ReaderName,
  OraIntrare,
  OraIesire
```

Comment: Do you know how to use GROUP BY ? That could be the start of your search.

Comment: Hello! I've edited my main query with what I've come up with.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code in Visual Basic in Distinct Database. Correct me if i'm wrong.

You can put this on form load. I think this is for combobox only. (not sure) but it works in my combobox it distinct my database.

> Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("select distinct [FULL NAME] from
>   EmpInfo", con1)
>
> ```
>     Dim table As New DataTable()
>     da.Fill(table)
>     ComboBox1.DataSource = New BindingSource(table, Nothing)
>     ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "FULL NAME"
> ```